# Kubernets docker registry behind nginx-ingress

Tags: kubernetes, ssl, ingress, docker-registry

I try to setup `docker-registry` in `Kubernetes` cluster behind the `nginx-ingress` controller.
The issue is, when I try to push the image into private registry, it tells me:

> Get https://registry.local/v2/: x509: certificate is valid for ingress.local, not registry.local

When I `curl` it, I get response from ingress' backend - 404.

Here's ingress' manifest:

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: docker-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts: [ 'registry.local' ]
  - secretName: registry
  rules:
  - host: registry.local
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: docker-registry
          servicePort: 5000
        path: /
```

And here's docker-registry manifest:

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  labels:
    app: docker-registry
  name: docker-registry
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: docker-registry
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: docker-registry
    spec:
      containers:
      - command:
        - /bin/registry
        - serve
        - /etc/docker/registry/config.yml
        env:
        - name: REGISTRY_HTTP_ADDR
          value: 0.0.0.0:5000
        - name: REGISTRY_STORAGE_FILESYSTEM_ROOTDIRECTORY
          value: /var/lib/registry
        - name: REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE
          value: /certs/ca.crt
        - name: REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY
          value: /certs/domain.key
        image: registry:2.6.2
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: docker-registry
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
          name: http
          protocol: TCP
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/lib/registry
          name: image-store
        - mountPath: /certs
          name: certs
      volumes:
      - name: image-store
        emptyDir: {}
      - name: certs
        configMap:
          name: certs
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  labels:
    app: docker-registry
  name: docker-registry
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 5000
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 5000
  selector:
    app: docker-registry
  type: ClusterIP
```

---

Separetly, nginx-ingress and docker-registry, work fine, but don't together.

Nothing valuabe from the ingress controller logs can be found.

Comment: I know this may seem obvious, but does the certificate actually exist?

Comment: Thank you, dude, for your response. But they did exist. Otherwise, it wouldn't tell `certificate is valid...`. The only thing about them, they're self-signed.

Comment: @acd `certificate is valid for ingress.local, not registry.local` indicates that the default fake ingress certificate is used. You have to add a valid certificate, i.e. one that matches the FQDN and has been issued by a trusted CA.

Comment: @030
Thank you for your suggestion, but it's not relevant. Because the cert I've generated (locally) was specifically issued to `registry.local` address. And, as I mentioned above, with that same cert `docker registry`, without `nginx` in front, works fine. And, with that same, another web service works fine behind that same `nginx`. The issue is with `nginx+docker`.

Answer (score 2):

First of all 404 error is resource error in kubernetes. It means your container in the pod is not created by your first script. Even if it is created and you can see it then your labeling is wrong in the second script.

I would suggest you check matchlabels of both YAML scripts. So in your case I can see that matchlabel is docker-registry in the spec section of the first script, but I don't see any docker-registry in the second script. I believe that in your metadata part of ingress script should have "name = docker-registry" instead of "name=docker-ingress".